# Question about apply integrals in finding volume of a pyramid?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

[image]

The answers entered already is what I got but either one or both are wrong.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: The number is $\frac{250}{3}\approx 83.33333$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first entry is right, if you choose $y=0$ at the bottom of the pyramid. So the volume is 
$$\int_0^{10}\frac{1}{4}(10-y)^2\,dy.$$

There must have been slippage in the evaluation of the integral, it should be $\frac{250}{3}$.

**Remark:** I would prefer to assume that the pyramid is pretty light, and turn it upside down, with the "apex" at the origin. Then the area of cross-section is $\frac{1}{4}y^2$, somewhat more pleasant.

Comment: You're right, my arithmetic in the end was the problem... Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: As a check of the result, you now know enough about volume integration to derive the formulas for a right circular cone (horizontal circular cross-sections tapering to a point) as $ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \pi \ r^2 h \ , $ one-third the volume of a cylinder with the same height and base radius, and by analogy, the formula for a square pyramid (square horizontal cross-sections tapering to a point), $ \ \frac{1}{3} \ s^2 h \ , $ one-third the volume of a rectangular prism with the same base and height.  For your pyramid, this gives $ \frac{1}{3} \cdot 5^2 \cdot 10 \ = \ \frac{250}{3} \ . $

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triangle whose base is a midline of the square base, parallel to an edge, and whose vertex is that of the pyramid.  Take a section at height  y from the base, and let its lenghth be  u.  Then its distance down from the top is  10 - y;  By similar triangles,
u / 5  =  (10 - y) / 10.
Then the width of the square is (10 - y) / 2

Its area (cross-section) is (10 - y)^2 / 4

So the volume of a thin slice, of thickness  δx,  (10 - y)^2 / 4 * δx.

Sum, and take limits as δx → 0:

The volume of the pyramid is

∫ [( (10 - y)^2 / 4 dy  for 0 ≤ y ≤ 10]

= [-(10 - y)^3 / 12 : 0 ≤ y ≤ 10]

= (1/12)*(1000 - 0)

= 250/3  =  83.3333...

(Oops!  mixed up y and x first go!  if you saw it)